# How to build a popup with firefox plugin?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to build a Firefox Addon. So when you press the button in the toolbar a sort of menu should appear.

[image]

I already got the button. But at developer.mozilla.org I only found how to add contextmenu, mainmenu or a popup.

**About my firefox plugin:**
I want to create a plugin which use ip-adress to get the current location. When you click on the button in my toolbar a sort of popup should appear (like in my picture) and show my location and the nearest trainstation/stops for bus and train with the trains and the time it will stop there. I got the API for this information.

Is it possible to build it just like the picture or do I have to use a popup?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it's possible.  Please be more specific. At a minimum, tell us what kind of Firefox add-on you are trying to write.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my post @Makyen

Comment: What kind of add-on (XUL, Restartless, Add-on SDK, WebExtensions)? For mobile? etc. You say you want "a sort of popup", but you are asking if you have to use a popup???? What is your actual issue? You want a popup that is not a popup??? I'm trying to point out that you are not being clear. Edit your question to link "contextmenu", "mainmenu" and "popup" at MDN so people know exactly what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The post by Jura is very outdated. To create a popup with SDK you would use the panel module as outlined here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel

To do the same with a WebExt you would do it like this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension#The_popup